# How to resolve Microsoft Reporting Services error: rsCredentialsNotSpecified

Tags: sql-server-2008

When passed a URL from the application, Reporting Services 2008 is erroring with **rsCredentialsNotSpecified**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open **Reporting Services Configuration Manager**
2. click **Report Manager URL** tab, browse to the URL specified
3. open the applications data manager section
4. specify credentials for the report server to use